# Unbalanced sample in dummy variable for OLS linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, unbalanced-classes, predictor, categorical-encoding

I have a linear model with the following variables:

- Y = continuous
- X1 = continuous
- X2 = continuous
- X3 = dichotomous (dummy coded)
- X4 = categorical (3 levels, dummy coded)

The X3 variable has unbalanced sample size in each group (n in group A = 30, n in group B = 100). I wonder if this unbalanced sample size for X3 variable would cause any problem for estimation of regression coefficients and hypothesis testing. If it does, is there any techniques for correction of this issue. By the way, in this model, a non-constant error was found and I correct this with heteroscedasticity corrected standard errors.

**UPDATE:** Just came up to my mind, but not sure my understanding was correct. If the major problem caused by unbalanced data was a violation of the assumption of homoscedasticity, which in turn leads to an inaccurate t value and p-value for inference, I was wondering if applying heteroscedasticity corrected standard errors would help address the issue caused by unbalanced data.

Thank you for your time!!